# DHCP sniff python3

Tags: python-3.x

i have seen this vid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imN-vhi5ZWQ&t=82s&ab_channel=KalleHallden
and i have try this code for DHCP SNIFF

```
import sys
import subprocess
import os
from decouple import config

IP_NETWORK = config('IP_NETWORK')
IP_DEVICE = config('IP_DEVICE')

proc = subprocess.Popen(['ping', IP_NETWORK], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    connected_ip = line.decode('utf-8').split[3]

    if connected_ip == IP_DEVICE:
        subprocess.Popen(['say', 'saar is home'])
```

when i try to run it i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "netsniff.py", line 6, in <module>
    IP_NETWORK = config('IP_NETWORK')
  File "/home/codeterminal/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/decouple.py", line 199, in __call__
    return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/codeterminal/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/decouple.py", line 83, in __call__
    return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/codeterminal/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/decouple.py", line 68, in get
    raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))
decouple.UndefinedValueError: IP_NETWORK not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.
```

Comment: I see `donfig` instead of `config` , is that expected? Seems like the `decouple` module expects either a `settings.ini` or `settings.env` file, can you follow what the module expects and try it out?

Comment: i have fix th 'dconfig' ty for it. i have try to change the .env file to settings.env/ini and same erorr l

Answer (score 0):

I guess IP_NETWORK should be defined as an environment variable and passed to your python process, for example:

```
IP_NETWORK=<your value here> python sniff.py
```

Comment: i have tried to make .env file but still i get the same erorr

Comment: You should fix typo at line where it says `donfig` and either define your environment variables as i mentioned in my answer or create a `.env` file in the same directory where your script is and fill it with values like `IP_NETWORK=<your value here>`, each value should be on a new line

Comment: i have done it and i have fix the typo and same erorr :/

Comment: just make sure that each value in the file `.env` is on a new line

Comment: each value is on new line

Comment: It's strange. How are you running your script?

Comment: python3 netsniff.py Through my terminal

Comment: i make it work but now when i ping the subnet mask i get this message:``ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable``